# Expo react-native build fails

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I created a react-native app with using Expo
and also setup github actions for automatic builds.

I got an error on build stage.

error was like

```
     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 7m 2s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
592 actionable tasks: 592 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.
```

since it's a unknown error, i do not know where to look at
why am I facing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to run it without the github actions? If not please check try and see if you can recreate the issue.
If you do, try:

```
cd android &&./gradlew clean
```

and then run the build command

Comment: unfortunately, i tried, same error continues